# Variable Manipulation not working as expected in macOS bash script

Tags: bash, macos, sed

Given:

```
itemName='boo\boo\1\7\064.txt'
```

I want to convert the octals to printables while removing unprintables. The catch: I don't want to remove backslashed alphas like the \b. The result should be:

```
newItemName='boo\boo4.txt'
```

I can't figure out why part of the sed statement doesn't work correctly:

```
newItemName="$(printf "%s" "$itemName" | sed -E 's/(\\[0-7]{1,3})/'"$(somevar="&";printf "${somevar:1}";)"'/g' | tr -dc '[:print:]')"
```

I used **somevar="&";** instead of directly accessing **&** so I could use variable manipulation.

The search statement **s/(\[0-7]{1,3})/** works fine.

In the printf if I use **$somevar** or **${somevar:0}** instead of **${somevar:1}** I get the original string as expected (e.g. \064).
What doesn't work is the **${somevar:1}**.
These also don't work: **${somevar/\/}** or **${somevar//\/}**.

1. What am I misunderstanding about how variable manipulation works?
2. Is there an easier way to do this? I've searched and searched...

Comment: `sed -E` - please check if you have `sed -E` on macos.[This sed on macos](https://ss64.com/osx/sed.html) seems not to have -E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam; long time no see! The problem here is the order of evaluation. All of the shell expressions, including the `$(somevar="&";printf "${somevar:1}";)`, are evaluated before sed is even launched. As a result, `somevar` isn't the string matched by the regex, it's just a literal ampersand. That means `${somevar:1}` is just the empty string, and you wind up just running `sed -E 's/(\\[0-7]{1,3})//g'`.

You need a way to take the matched string and run a calculation on it (*after* it's been matched), and sed just isn't flexible enough to do this. But perl is. perl has an `s` operator, similar to sed's, but with the `e` option the replacement is executed as a perl expression rather than just a literal string. Give this a try:

```
newItemName="$(printf "%s\n" "$itemName" | perl -pe 's/\\([0-7]{1,3})/chr oct $1/eg' | tr -dc '[:print:]')"
```

Comment: @SamuelHerschbein That's just resulting in a literal `&`, so that's what's passed to `sed` as the replacement. Try running `set -x` before it (and on macOS, `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` to remove background chatter), and the shell will print the equivalent of what it's actually executing. Use `set +x` to turn it off.

Answer (score -1):

> What am I misunderstanding about how variable manipulation works?

I believe you are misunderstanding how `sed` works.

When `&` character is used inside the replacement string, it is replaced by the whole string matched. See [this sed introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-3).

Now about [`${var:offset}` parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
somevar=&
printf "$somevar"
```

would print `&`. Then:

```
printf "${somevar:1}"
```

would extract substring starting at offset 1 to the end of string. The first character is at offset, well, 0, so at at offset 1 there is no character, because out variable `somevar` has one character. So it will print nothing.

```
printf "${somevar:0}"
```

would print a substring starting at offset 0 to the end of the string. So the whole string. So `${somevar:0}` is equal to `$somevar`. It will print `&`.

So:

```
$(somevar="&";printf "${somevar:1}";)
```

expands to nothing, because `${somevar:1}` expands to nothing. So you sed command looks like this:

```
sed -E 's/(\\[0-7]{1,3})//g'
```

The sed command substitutes a `\` character followed by a number `0-7` one to 3 times for nothing, multiple times. It does what you want.

Now if it would be `${somevar:0}` then:

```
$(somevar="&";printf "${somevar:0}";)
```

expands to `&`, so your sed command would look like this:

```
sed -E 's/(\\[0-7]{1,3})/&/g'
```

so it would substitute a `\\[0-7]{1,3}` for *itself*. Ie. it does nothing.

You could loose the `-E` option and `(...)` backreference, and just use posixly compatible `sed`:

```
sed 's/\\[0-7]\{1,3\}//g'
```

> Is there an easier way to do this?

Your method looks fine. You could use a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) instead of printf and you could strengthen the sed to match octal numbers better, depending on needs:

```
newItemName="$(
        <<<"$itemName" sed 's/\\\([0-3][0-7]\{0,2\}\|[0-7]\{1,2\}\)//g' |
        tr -dc '[:print:]'
)"
```